# Printing prawn generated pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, prawn

Using prawn gem for ruby-on-rails webpage, is it possible to send print request to printer device to print pdf page I've generated using prawn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you would want to use [prawn-print](https://rubygems.org/gems/prawn-print).

```
# Open print dialog, but don't autoprint.
pdf = Prawn::Document.new
pdf.text "I installed Adobe Reader and all I got was this lousy printout."
pdf.print

# Autoprint it on the default printer, when opened.
pdf = Prawn::Document.new
pdf.text "Help! I am trapped in a PDF factory!"
pdf.autoprint

# Autoprint it on a printer where the name includes "LaserJet".
pdf = Prawn::Document.new
pdf.text "Help! I am trapped in a PDF factory!"
pdf.autoprint "LaserJet"
```

Comment: Awesome, at first it wasn't working, but the problem is that I'm developing on linux, on Windows it works great (because windows users use adobe reader)

Comment: Presumably this uses Javascript to trigger the printing, so it'll only work on Adobe Acrobat. No other software vendor is silly enough to add JS to a PDF reader.